# assignment of a value to a value changing in for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

in a previous question i had a problem in some code,, after revealed, i had other problem in the code:

```
i=1;
double smallest=diff[i][2];
int nxtcty;
for (j=2; j<=n; j++)
        {
          if (j!=i && diff[i][j]<smallest) {smallest=diff[i][j]; nxtcty=j;}
        }
```

the value nxtcty is not changing to j.. it outputs a strange number which i believe it is the memory location content for it >> '134520820'.. what went wrong??
thank you in advance...

EDIT
for further debugging, here the full code.. it is a very beginner code to calculate distance between several cities with their (x,y) coordinates given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
        {
          int i, j, n;
////////////// getting the number of cities ///////////////////
                printf("how many cities are there?\n");
                scanf("%d", &n); printf("so there is %d cities\n", n);
                int x[n];
                int y[n];
///////////// getting the x coordinates //////////////////////
                printf("enter their x coordinates, each followed by return\n");
                for (i=0; i<n; i++)
                        {
                          scanf("%d", &x[i]);
                          printf("the %dth city x coordinate is %d\n", i+1, x[i]);
                        }
///////////// getting the y cordinates /////////////////////
                printf("enter their y coordinates, each followed by return\n");
                for (i=0; i<n; i++)
                        {
                          scanf("%d", &y[i]);
                          printf("the %dth city y coordinate is %d\n", i+1, y[i]);
                        }
////////////// showing information ///////////////////////
                for (i=0; i<n; i++)
                        {
                          printf("city number %d is at (%d,%d)\n", i+1, x[i], y[i]);
                        }
//////////// get the distances /////////////////
double diff[n][n];
double h;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
          {
                h=((x[i]-x[j])*(x[i]-x[j])+(y[i]-y[j])*(y[i]-y[j]));
                printf("city #%d distance %lf from city #%d\n\n", i+1, sqrt(h), j+1);
                diff[i][j]=sqrt(h);
          }
    }

for (i=0; i<n; i++) {for (j=0; j<n; j++)
{ printf("%lf  ", diff[i][j]);
if (j!=0 && n % (j+1)==0){printf("\n");}}
}
i=0;
double smallest=diff[i][1];
printf("smallest_initial   %lf \n",smallest);
int nxtcty=77;
printf("nxtcty_initial %d\n",nxtcty);
for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
        {
          printf("j_b4_if: %d,  smallest_b4_if:  %lf, nxtcty_b4_if:   %d\n",j, smallest, nxtcty);
          if ( diff[i][j]<smallest ) {smallest=diff[i][j]; nxtcty=j;
              printf("j_in_if: %d,  smallest_in_if:  %lf, nxtcty_in_if:   %d\n",j, smallest, nxtcty); }
printf("j_in_for: %d,  smallest_in_for:  %lf, nxtcty_in_for:   %d\n",j, smallest, nxtcty);
        }
printf("j %d,,  nxtcty %d\n", j, nxtcty);
                 return 0;
        }
```

Comment: What's `n`? That could be it.

Comment: Do you not need a semi-colon after the assignment of j to nxtcty in C?

Comment: @Rafe n is the size of array diff[i][j]

Comment: @George i've actually put it in the code,, the error exists only here.. thank you, i'll edit it for correction..

Comment: @Amy I really didn't know. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If would be a good idea to initialise nxtcty to 2 so that if diff[i][2] really is the smallest then will be the index of the smallest and not still uninitialised.

If you think that an assignment should be taking place, try printing out diff[i][j] each time round the loop to check.

Comment: thank you @MRAB .. the code works well without nxtcty,, getting the smallest value of the first row in diff[i][j] array.. nxtcty is supposed to be the column number 'j' in which the smallest value is.. the if loop is not working... any idea??

Comment: The second printf is inside the body of the 'if' statement, so it'll print only if the condition is true, which, apparently, it never is. Put a printf just before the 'if' statement to show diff[i][j] and smallest. With that I expect that you'll find that diff[i][j] is never less than smallest.

Comment: thank you @MRAB. actually i did what u suggested and smallest changes,, i did a test where the initial value of `smallest` >>which is `diff[1][2]` is not the smallest,, and watched `smallest` changes to the smallest value due to the for loop.. however,, no clue that the if-statement is working... am kinda stuck here!!!

Comment: This is wrong "for (j=1; j<=n; j++)" because for an array of size n the index should be in the range is 0..n-1. Apart from that it works for me.

Comment: @MRAB j is meant to initiate the second value since `diff[1][1]` is zero,, but yeah it has to be: `j<n` .. it worked 4u?? nxtcty was assigned to the last value of j,, nd the if-statement worked?? it didnt for me!!!

Comment: Did you look at the values it printed? Should the body of the if statement have been executed? What were your input values?

Comment: my inputs (once among many times i tried) were 3 cities, at (1,1) , (2,2) , and (3,3).. the results of all program was perfect yet `nxtcty` aint changing from `77` >>the initialized value (i chose roughly)... and actually `j_in_if` , `smallest_in_if` and `nxtcty_in_if` never printed, indicating that if-statement werent true at all... what were yours??

Comment: With those values, of course nxtcty won't change. Just look at the distances. There is _no_ later distance which is smaller than the initial smallest value. Try 3 cities at (1,1), (3,3) and (2,2) (in that order). Now the initial smallest isn't the smallest of all.

Comment: although i've tried the exact sequence u said before nd gave me wrong results,, but when i tried it now it went well.. there must be something wrong i did the first time,, or i may have been way too sleepy.. thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you ever hit the statement that assigns the value of j to nxtcty? If not, what you see is the initial (uninitialized) value of nxtcty.

Comment: sry,, the previous comment was wrong.. @500 ,, j printed (as in the edited code in the question) -printed 4 >which is normal.. but nxtcty is 134520820 before and after the assignment.. which means the assignment process is not correct i guess.. any ideas??

Comment: If nxtcty is 134520820 both before and after it means the `if` condition in the loop is never met. This means the smallest element is the first one, `diff[i][2]`. You can put a `printf` within the `if` statement block to confirm this. You should also initialize nxtcty to 2.

Comment: thank you @uesp .. well,, after assigning nxtcty to 2: it stuck to 2 !! AND the bad news is: the printf within the if statement is not working!! it never shows up anything... that tells me something about the code: smallest for some reason is resulted right from the for loop without the need for if statement!!!

Comment: It may also help to add a `printf()` within your for loop to output the values of `diff[i][j]` assuming there aren't too many of them. Or step through the loop with a debugger while inspecting the variables. This should make it more obvious why the code is doing what it is doing and not what you think it should be.

Comment: thank you @uesp .. i did.. actually the whole thing goes great, `j` keeps increasing and `smallest` is the right value... however,, if-statement DOES NOT work.. if i put `nxtcty=j` outside the if-statement it responds, but that is not what i want,, i want it to be equal to `j` only `if (diff[i][j]<smallest) ` ... any ideas ???!!

Comment: When you say "not working" I assume you mean the statements in the if block are never run. This is almost certainly due to the if expression never becoming true. For example `if (2 == 3) { }` will never be true so the statements within the block will never run. Similarly, if `diff[i][] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` your if expression of `diff[i][j] < smallest` will never be true and your if block will never run. If you need more help I suggest adding a minimal compilable sample including the definition/contents of `diff[][]`.

Comment: thank you @uesp.. i just added the full code with a very brief description for its purpose in the question..